# What is the general name for shapes like sphere and cone?

Tags: 3d

What is the general name of the shapes you get by spinning a 2d shape around 360 degrees? e.g spinning right triangle around either short sides 360 degrees to get a cone, spinning a circle around the diameter to get sphere, etc

Comment: [Solids of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a thing is called [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution).